# Modify the generic block layer in a Linux system

Tags: linux, io, ssd

For an university project, I need to modify a kernel layer in a Linux operating system. After modification I should prove performance improvements.

Concrete I should modify the generic block layer and change the maximum request size for merging blocks. The Linux distrubution is located at my university and I have access **via** **ssh**. The version is: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-70-generic x86_64).

Although I know something about I/O designs and ssds, I unfortunately don't have any clue how to get started. Is this excercise even possible over the command lines? I would be happy if someone could give me a kick start or small hints.

Comment: "After modification I should prove performance improvements".  So, lie?

Comment: To modify kernel code, you need a text editor and a compiler. Both are available on the command line. However, it's probably preferable to install the precise Ubuntu version at home and do the work there. Start with kernel documentation, most probably https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/block/index.html as well as the https://kernelnewbies.org/ web site.